# How to get this layout responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I can't figure out how to get my layout to be how it should, the idea is for it to be like the following:

```
  +-------------------------------------------------+
  |  logo      |          Menu                      |
  |            |------------------------------------+
  |------------|                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |Menu        |  where the layout will change      |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |------------|------------------------------------|
  |  logo      |          footer                    |
  +-------------------------------------------------+
```

this and my main screen, I ask you to examine my code, or if they see fit, only assemble the structure I lay back all the code above.

```
<body class="sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper ">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg" style="background-color: #252525;">
            <div class="row navbar" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 35px;">
                <img src="~/Images/tecbox/logo_tecbox.png" style="max-height: 80px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
<section class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="~/Home/Cadastros" style="background-color: #375DC0;">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Cadastros</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #8e4e71;">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Movimentações</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #CE603B; ">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Financeiro</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #E38C23; ">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Comercial</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #96A040; ">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Configurações</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-principal">
            <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #DEB887; ">
                @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Relatórios</span>
                @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 60px; text-align:center; background-color: #363636">
                <img src="~/Images/logo-infoworld.png" style="max-width: 150px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 text-center" style="background-color: black;">
            <div class="row navbar navbar-static-top" style="background-color: steelblue;">
                <div class="navbar-custom-menu" style="width: 100%;">
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left;">
                        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button" style="height: 60px;">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" style="color: white; font-size: 20px;">
                            <img src="~/Images/tecbox/icons/home-icon.png" style="max-height: 40px; padding-left: 5px;" />
                            <span class="hidden-xs">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4" style="color: white;">
                        <span>nome da loja - bla bla - bla bla</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="hidden-xs" style="padding-right: 10px;">Negrini</span>
                            <img src="~/Images/tecbox/semFoto300x300.png" alt="Foto" class="image-semfoto" />
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu menu-superior">
                            <!-- User image -->
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Alterar imagem da conta</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Alterar senha</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Histórico de acessos</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Trocar loja</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Bloquear</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Sobre</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="divider" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Trocar usuário</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-header">
                                <a>
                                    <span>
                                        <b>Sair</b>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar" style="height: 60px;"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <section class="content" ng-model="idForTransactions" ng-controller="MainController">
                    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    <section class="sidebar">
                        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="~/Home/Cadastros" style="background-color: #375DC0;">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Cadastros</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #8e4e71;">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Movimentações</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #CE603B; ">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Financeiro</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #E38C23; ">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Comercial</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #96A040; ">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Configurações</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu-principal">
                                <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html" style="background-color: #DEB887; ">
                                    @*<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>*@ <span>Relatórios</span>
                                    @*<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>*@
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-fuchsia bottom" style="padding: 15px;">
                rodapé
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<-- scripts -->
</body>
```

actual situation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHcRo.png

as the note, neither party reaches the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You want to have responsiveness only inside the content area? where it says `where the layout will change`?

Comment: Look at your third line, one of the classes say `col-lg` - I'm pretty sure you need to set a value. i.e. `col-lg-2`. Also, it seems like some of the divs are not closed in the right order.

Comment: just want to say what changes the screen is that part. on non-closed div, they are all closed = /

Comment: If only the content area is changing, then that's not really a responsive web page. That's just a web page with a fluid section.

Comment: @DA. Ok, but follows the problem ... I can not come up with the layout until the bottom of the page, and about being responsive, if I resize the browser, it will break.

Comment: If it's not an actual responsive page, then bootstrap is probably causing more problems than it's solving. I think you're looking for a more traditional "2 column layout, one column fluid"

Comment: @DA. if this resolves, I await your response ... I will continue having trouble resizing?

Answer (score 0):

This layout is what you need to work with and is responsive:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"><!--START NAVBAR-->
        <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="http://welcome.hp-ww.com/country/us/en/cs/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo.gif" alt="lala" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="http://welcome.hp-ww.com/country/us/en/cs/images/i/header-footer/caas-hf-v3/hp-logo.gif" alt="lala" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div><!--END NAVBAR-->
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10"><!--START CONTENT-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                Blue bar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                Black bar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                Pink bar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--END CONTENT-->
</div>
```

Comment: this layout not fill my screen.

Comment: please, see the link in question

Comment: Just for build layout it will help you to build quickly the wrapper and understand how boostrap grid system works. Hope helped you! Regards Interface builder for boostrap http://www.layoutit.com/en